# How to extract HTML links from a table using Selenium?

Tags: java, html, parsing, selenium, web

I am using the following code using Java and Selenium:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    WebDriver driver;
    DesiredCapabilities caps; 
    caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            "lib/phantomjs.exe"); 
    caps.setBrowserName(DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs().getBrowserName());
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.cdp.net/en-US/Pages/CDPAdvancedSearchResults.aspx?k=microsoft");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("ms-vb2"));
    String text = element.getText();
    String href = element.getAttribute("href");
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
    driver.quit();
    System.out.println(text + " " + href);  
}
```

The specific portion of the page I am trying with the code contains the following. I am trying to extract the href from class `ms-vb2`, which is `https://www.cdp.net/en-US/Results/Pages/Company-Responses.aspx?company=11930`:

```
<td class="ms-vb2"><a href="https://www.cdp.net/en-US/Results/Pages/Company-Responses.aspx?company=11930">Microsoft Corporation</a><br/>USA</td>
```

I am getting the text but I am not getting the href. How can I extract that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`driver.findElement(By.className("ms-vb2"))` would actually match the `td` element:

```
<td class="ms-vb2"><a href="https://www.cdp.net/en-US/Results/Pages/Company-Responses.aspx?company=11930">Microsoft Corporation</a><br>USA</td>
```

and it does not have an `href` attribute.

You need to locate the link inside. I would make a CSS selector:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ms-vb2 > a"))
```

Here we are searching for an `a` element directly inside the element having `ms-vb2` class.